# mySql - get common values from multiple queries

Tags: mysql

My database table looks like this:

[image]

I am trying to run a query that would return all the common user_id's where - for instance, `field_id = 552 AND value = 'Savannah' AND field_id = 553 AND value = 'GA' AND field_id = 554 AND value = 'USA'`. (so in this case, based on the records visible in my screenshot, the result would simply be '1').

I've been looking at joins and unions, but I feel I've gone down a rabbit hole and can't find my way back out.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one option using `conditional aggregation`:

```
select user_id
from yourtable
group by user_id
having max(case when field_id = 552 then value end) = 'Savannah' and
       max(case when field_id = 553 then value end) = 'GA' and
       max(case when field_id = 554 then value end) = 'USA'
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b6d923/1)

Comment: This seems to do exactly what I need it to, thank you.